# Timer capture STM32

Tags: stm32, timer

I have some questions about timer capture in the STM32.  Is it possible to capture a digital signal? Like this:

[image: Digital signal]

Actually, I'd like to know how many clock ticks between rising and falling edge, in every pulse.

Comment: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/91/01/84/3f/7c/67/41/3f/DM00236305/files/DM00236305.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00236305.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1st situation: No info about signals frequency

Certainly, if you measure the input signal with the timer and accept the minimum time between the rising and the lowering edge as 1 clock, you can obtain the signal in STM32. If there is not a single "1" data in the signal, unfortunately the frequency of the signal you find will be lower than it should.

- 2nd situation: If the signal frequency is known

There's no need for assumption about frequency.

I would advise you to examine document submitted from `Scott Seidman`